# Certificate authentication to Graph API in Azure Automation Account

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm trying to authenticate to the Graph API through Powershell (5.1) using a certificate in an automation account runbook.

I've created a private key and certificate into a password protected PFX. It's uploaded to the 'Certificate' section in my automation account. I've tested to upload it manually in the portal and using New-AzAutomationCertificate, exportable and non-exportable.

I have tested:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users

$AppId = '<app id>'
$TenantId = '<tenant id>'

$cert = Get-AzAutomationCertificate -ResourceGroupName "automation" -AutomationAccountName "aa-automation-common" -Name "cert-auth-prod-exportable"

Connect-MgGraph -Certificate $cert -TenantId $TenantId -ClientId $AppId

Get-MgUser -UserId "<user id>"
```

And

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users

$AppId = '<app id>'
$TenantId = '<tenant id>'

$cert = (Get-AzAutomationCertificate -ResourceGroupName "automation" -AutomationAccountName "aa-automation-common" -Name "cert-auth-prod-exportable").Thumbprint

Connect-MgGraph -CertificateThumbprint $cert -TenantId $TenantId -ClientId $AppId

Get-MgUser -UserId "<user id>"
```

Both results in an error when running in the runbook in Azure.

```
Get-AzAutomationCertificate : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. At line:6 char:10 + $cert = (Get-AzAutomationCertificate -ResourceGroupName "automation" ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzAutomationCertificate], NullReferenceException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Automation.Cmdlet.GetAzureAutomationCertificate
```

When I test it locally in VS Code by first signing in using Connect-AzAccount both works fine. I get the certificate info, can connect using Connect-MgGraph and fetch the user info.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a password protected PFX and uploaded it to the **'Certificates'** section in my automation account:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment, I too got **same error** as below:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users

$AppId = 'appId'
$TenantId = 'tenantId'

$cert = (Get-AzAutomationCertificate -ResourceGroupName "Sri" -AutomationAccountName "testautomation" -Name "GraphCert").Thumbprint
Connect-MgGraph -CertificateThumbprint $cert -TenantId $TenantId -ClientId $AppId
Get-MgUser -UserId "xxxxxxxx"
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, the error occurred as you missed calling **Connect-AzAccount** that is necessary for `Get-AzAutomationCertificate` command to work.

To resolve the error, I turned on **system-managed** identity of automation account and added `Contributor` (a Reader role would be enough) role to it like below:

[image]

When I ran below modified script by connecting to Azure via  **system-managed** identity, I got the **response** with user details successfully like below:

```
# Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process

$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users

$AppId = 'appId'
$TenantId = 'tenantId'

$cert = (Get-AzAutomationCertificate -ResourceGroupName "Sri" -AutomationAccountName "testautomation" -Name "GraphCert").Thumbprint
Connect-MgGraph -CertificateThumbprint $cert -TenantId $TenantId -ClientId $AppId
Get-MgUser -UserId "xxxxxxxx"
```

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

[image]

In your case, make sure to call **Connect-AzAccount** before running  `Get-AzAutomationCertificate` command.

**Reference:**
[Using a system-assigned managed identity for an Azure Automation account | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/enable-managed-identity-for-automation#authenticate-access-with-system-assigned-managed-identity)

Comment: Awesome, works just fine. Thanks a lot! I would like to add that it is possible to use a less privileged role/permission. I added the Reader role to the Managed identity only on the Automation account to avoid having permissions within the entire subscription. This worked fine as well.